# How to implement virtual UNC mapping in a Windows user session?

Tags: windows, powershell, server-message-block, unc

I need to implement virtual SMB UNC mapping in a Windows user session.

Similar to what "NET USE H: \\realhost\share" command does, but redirect  "\\virtualhost\share" to "\\realhost\share" instead.

The mapping should affect only the relevant Windows user Session, not the whole machine.

Is there a way and which is the best way to implement such a mapping, preferably  with PowerShell or by a component written in C#?

Comment: that's what kgon scripts do when they have been applied in the user settings.

Comment: @djdomi what is a kgon script?

Comment: logon script, I ain't feasible using android keyboard and the answers become more funny ;)

Comment: @djdomi which command will you put in a user logon script to map a non existing \\virtualhost\share name to an existing \\realhost\share ?

Comment: your question is unclear. if you want to use dfs then that's the way, but at the current point of view I can only guess what you want to solve

Comment: @djdomi DFS namespaces is not a solution because it is not in the user session and its root is not virtual. As described in my question I am asking for a virtual SMB UNC path. If the "-LocalPath" parameter of the PowerShell cmdlet "New-SmbMapping" was accepting a virtual UNC path instead of just virtual drive letter that would have been just fine. I hope it is now more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151541/discussion-between-tchoha-and-djdomi).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a group policy which maps the mapping in the session. Or specify it the user attribute in active directory